# Do inputs inside a fieldset outside of a form need to have the form-attribute as well?

Tags: html, forms

If I have form-elements outside the actual form, I can link them using the `form`-attribute:

```
<form id="test"></form>
<input form="test"></form>
```

Now I have a fieldset outside the form, which I can link in the same way:

```
<form id="test"></form>
<fieldset form="test">
    <input>
</fieldset>
```

Unfortunately w3.org [4.10.16 The fieldset element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-fieldset-element) doesn't say anything about the children:

> The form attribute is used to explicitly associate the fieldset element with its form owner.

So my question is:
*Are inputs inside the `fieldset` automatically attached to the `form` as well or do I have to add the `form`-attribute on each child-element explicitly?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A form control is not associated with its form owner via an ancestor fieldset element, so you have to associate the control to its form explicitly.

In any case, you are better off testing this in browsers to establish the current reality than relying on what the spec might say.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any source about that? Or does the quoted specs in my question actually imply it?

Comment: @lampshade - Close by really. [4.10.17.3. Association of controls and forms](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms) explains how the association works. It doesn't include any special behaviour for fieldsets.

Comment: @Alohci Brilliant, I lost quite a bit of time trying to figure out why the fields inside my linked fieldset weren't submitting with the form. Thank you!